# WPF Bind ListBox to DataSet

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, dataset

I am trying to get a dataset to display in a `ListBox`. Here is what I have got so far:

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="FilterDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FilterDemo" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded_1" >
<Window.Resources>
    <local:FilterDemoBackEndDataSet x:Key="FilterDemoBackEndDataSet"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cLIENTSViewSource" Source="{Binding CLIENTS, Source={StaticResource FilterDemoBackEndDataSet}}"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Background="#c4d9f9" >
        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Width="220"  Margin="10,5,5,5">
            <TextBox Name="txtSearch" Height="20" Width="160" DockPanel.Dock="Left"  />
            <Button Name="cmdFilter" Height="20" Width="20"  Background="Black" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
        </DockPanel>

        <ListBox Name="lstAccountNo"  Height="550"  Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DisplayMemberPath="AccountNo" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                             Margin="10,5,5,5" SelectedItem="{Binding AccountNo}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

`Code behind`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace FilterDemo
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
      public MainWindow()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
          FilterDemo.FilterDemoBackEndDataSet FilterDemoBackEndDataSet = ((FilterDemo.FilterDemoBackEndDataSet)(this.FindResource("FilterDemoBackEndDataSet")));
          // Load data into the table CLIENTS. You can modify this code as needed.
          FilterDemo.FilterDemoBackEndDataSetTableAdapters.CLIENTSTableAdapter FilterDemoBackEndDataSetCLIENTSTableAdapter = new FilterDemo.FilterDemoBackEndDataSetTableAdapters.CLIENTSTableAdapter();
          FilterDemoBackEndDataSetCLIENTSTableAdapter.Fill(FilterDemoBackEndDataSet.CLIENTS);
          System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource cLIENTSViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("cLIENTSViewSource")));
          cLIENTSViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
      }
  }
}
```

I have a dataset called `FilterDemoBackEnd`, a Table called `Clients` and a Field called `AccountNo`. When I run the above code the window opens up but no items are displayed.

Please no answers with a link to a thread as I have scoured the internet trying to sort this out.

XAML is tough.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out by dragging a data grid to the mainwindow and then deleting it. I'm not sure how this helped but it did the trick.